# how to make select box dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I've three `select-box` here to choose **Format**, **Amount** & **Shipping type**. After selection, it will calculate price automatically.

here, how those `select-box` look like:

```
<p>Format: <select class="calculate" name="format">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <option value="0">Format 1</option>
    <option value="0">Format 2</option>
    </select></p>

<p>Amount: <select class="calculate" name="amount">
    <option value="0">Select amount</option>
    <option value="247">250pcs</option>
    <option value="279">1,000pcs</option>
    <option value="389">2,500pcs</option>
    </select></p>

<p>Shipping type: <select id="surcharge" name="shipping">
    <option value="0">Select Shipping</option>
    <option value="10%">Standard</option>
    <option value="15%">Express</option>
    </select></p>
```

currently, the **Amount** for the both **Format** (Format 1/Format 2) are same.

**what i'm trying to do is like:** for the **Format 1**, the current **Amount** will remain same, but if user select **Format 2** then the **Amount** will something like this:

```
        <option value="0">Select amount</option>
        <option value="300">250pcs</option>
        <option value="350">1,000pcs</option>
        <option value="400">2,500pcs</option>
```

where the `value` is different! how can i achive this?

here goes the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neshpro9/7Bfk5/9/)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should checkout using `change` events with jQuery, it'll get you started

Comment: ok, got it.. i can see examples from the answer! thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking the `text()` in the options you are selecting

```
if ($('#sel option:selected').text() === 'Format 2') {
    $('#amt option').each(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
        if ($(this).text() == "250pcs") $(this).val("300");
        else if ($(this).text() == "1,000pcs") $(this).val("350");
        else $(this).val("400");
    });
}
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bfk5/20/)

Comment: well, i guess i like your `text()` approach because i want to keep the **value** of the **Format** `0`. thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thats okay, So you go with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

You should first set the new values in an array. So you can loop through them while changing the first select.

Then you can easily get the options from the 2nd select, and update them with the correct new values:

```
    $(".calculate, #surcharge").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1)
    {
        var amountValues = new Array(0,250,400,500);

        $("#menge option").each(function(key,value)
        {
            $(this).val(amountValues[key]);
          });
    } else if($(this).val() == 2)
    {
        var amount Values = new Array();
       // .....
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Bfk5/15/

Comment: thanks & vote up for your answer! i'll come back after give a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that does values/options replacement and call it on your select changes.
I did an example for you but used static html options to replace old ones, this might not be the best way but tried to keep it as simple as possible.

HTML

```
    <p>Format: <select class="calculate format" name="format">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Format 1</option>
    <option value="2">Format 2</option>
    </select></p>

<p>Amount: <select class="calculate amount" name="menge">
    <option value="0">Select Menge</option>
    <option value="247">250pcs</option>
    <option value="279">1,000pcs</option>
    <option value="389">2,500pcs</option>
    </select></p>

<p>Shipping type: <select id="surcharge" name="shipping">
    <option value="0">Select Shipping</option>
    <option value="10%">Standard</option>
    <option value="15%">Express</option>
    </select></p>

<p>Price: <span id="total">0 €</span></p>
```

Javascript

```
    var updateValues = function (){
    if($('.format').val() == 1) {
        html = '<option value="300">300pcs</option>';
        html += '<option value="400">400pcs</option>';
        html += '<option value="500">500pcs</option>';
         $('.amount').html(html);
    } else if( $('.format').val() == 2) {
        html = '<option value="600">600pcs</option>';
        html += '<option value="900">900pcs</option>';
        html += '<option value="1200">1200pcs</option>';
         $('.amount').html(html);
    }
};
$('.format').change(function(){updateValues()});
$(".calculate, #surcharge").on("change", function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.calculate').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != 0) {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });
        if($('#surcharge').val() != 0) {
          total = total * ((100 + parseFloat($('#surcharge').val())) / 100);
        }
        $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2) + ' €');
    });
```

Fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/7Bfk5/23/

Comment: thanks for your help & effort! i really do appreciate it but i just have to mark only 1 as answer!